# Android POST data to local server using webview error

Tags: javascript, android, server

I have a local server with a static IP 192.168.1.3:8080 hosted geoserver using appach tomcat, I want to send a gps data from my phone to Geoserver, which also has a static IP "192.168.1.233:8080", The android application side is a simple webview, I use loadURL function to load html and java script that using 'POST' to push data to server.

The webpage and Js code work perfect (no syntax error or throw..etc)

```
String JSCODE = "<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> TEST <script>"+JSCODE_nonhtml+ "</script> </head> </html>";

WebView _wbv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
                _wbv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                _wbv.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                _wbv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                _wbv.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

 _wbv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", JSCODE, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

When i launch the application I get this error:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.3:8080/geoserver/wfs' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.", source: about:blank (0)
```

I know there is CORS problem, so how i can fix this both on android and PC server.
thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I Added the following command to

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\web.xml

of the tomcat server configuration

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

Comment: My port to list in myserver is 8080

Comment: Try your servers with a browser on your Android device first. Further we do not see you use http urls. Android version of used device?

Comment: @blackapps i get the same error too!

Comment: You could post your error in such a way that we dont have to scroll horizontalle half an hour... And why dont you answer all question?

Comment: http url was prepaed on Oncreate method

Comment: All has nothing to do with Android or posting. So please write a different post.